# Two pipes in c program and the second one does not work as expected

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, dup2

I am currently making some tests with the pipes and forks in C.
I am trying to copy the behavior of this shell command in my program:

```
cat < test | wc
```

The test file contains only a little text.
Here is my program's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// cat < test | wc
int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int     p1[2];
    int     pid1;

    printf("\nBegin of the test...\n");
    if (pipe(p1) == -1)
    {
        perror("Pipe1");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 > 0)
        {
            int     p2[2];
            int     pid2;

            close(p1[0]);
            if (pipe(p2) == -1)
            {
                perror("Pipe1");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                pid2 = fork();
                if (pid2 > 0)
                {
                    int             pid3;

                    close(p1[1]);
                    pid3 = fork();
                    if (pid3 > 0)
                    {
                        close(p2[1]);
                        wait(0);
                        printf("All is done !\n");
                    }
                    else if (pid3 == 0)
                    {
                        close(p2[1]);
                        dup2(p2[0], 0);
                        execve("/usr/bin/wc", av, NULL);
                    }
                    wait(0);
                }
                else if (pid2 == 0)
                {
                    int     fd;
                    char    buffer[20];
                    int     ret;

                    close(p2[0]);
                    dup2(p2[1], 1);
                    fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
                    if (fd >= 0)
                    {
                        while ((ret = read(fd, buffer, 20)) > 0)
                            write(p1[1], buffer, ret);
                        close(fd);
                        close(p1[1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        perror("Open file error");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    close(p1[1]);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            wait(0);
        }
        else if (pid1 == 0)
        {
            close(p1[1]);
            dup2(p1[0], 0);
            execve("/bin/cat", av, NULL);   
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnd of the program.\n");
    return (1);
}
```

The output is:

```
Begin of the test...
All is done !
Content of the test file
       0       0       0

End of the program.
```

Can someone explain to me why the cat output is not redirected to the wc through the pipe 2?

Comment: Have you come across popen? It's like system except you get 1 pipe either to stdin *OR* stdout.  It may make things easier

Comment: I see two `pipe()`s and three `fork()`s, too much! You should have only one pipe and two processes so one `fork()`!

Comment: @rhubarbdog : I would like to do it with pipe and fork, I know the popen but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I am not sure about it, I am pretty sure I need at least 2 pipes and at least 1 or 2 forks, to do what I want.

Comment: One process for `cat`, one for `wc` and one pipe in between. Explain why you want another pipe and process..

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès : Because my program to continue after excve. My goal is to build a full shell.

Comment: Ok but you used 3 `fork()`s so you have four process (the initial one counts); and you don't need two pipes but only one to communicate through the two children. shell forks two times to create two processes one execing to `cat`, the second execing to `wc`; both communicating through a single pipe. The initial process (the shell) just have to wait its children to finish.